# more memory allocation in java program

Tags: java, memory, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit and my system has 4 GB RAM.

I run a java program that need more than 1.1GB memory but the operating system does not allow my program to get more than 1.1GB while only 2.1GB of RAM is used and 1.9GB are free, what is the problem? (This problem is not just for this program, I run another program and has same problem.)

what should I do?

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` tell you when you run it with the same user you use for those programs?

Comment: It says that *max memory size* is unlimited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running a java application. Make sure to

- Run a 64 bit JVM, if you need more than about 4GB memory. For this to work, you shold have a 64 bit OS
- Increase the max heap size by the JVM switch 
  `-Xms <initial size> -Xmx <max size>`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you programs are compiled as 32bit programs despite that you are running on a 64bit configuration.

Comment: I run my project with eclipse so I think it can not be the problem

Comment: What specific error are you getting, and how did you link the program etc.

Comment: Also what does your `ulimit -a` look like?

Comment: I get this error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: So you are not running a native program (i.e. not written in C)  but a Java Interpreted program -- you may want to check which JRE you are using and I bet it is a 32bit version.